# Russian equivalent of the colloquial figurative expression "get left out of the loop"

Tags: одним-словом

In English, you can say "leave someone out of the loop" to mean "leave them out of the discussion"; for instance, three people are talking among themselves, and you feel sort of alienated, not being part of the conversation.

> **исключить** кого-то **из обсуждения**
>
> {or}: я **исключён из обсуждения**

I think this phrasing is rather straightforward. I wonder if there is another idiomatic expression  used colloquially and figuratively/metaphorically?

Comment: Incidentally, there are equivalent figurative expressions: In French "laissé sur la touche". In German: "außen vor gelassen werden". In Japanese: "蚊帳の外".

Comment: _To leave out of the loop_ means "to disconnect from the channels of update of information" - not exactly from "discussion". So Russian translation will be something like "оставлять в неведении".

Comment: @farfareast Hi. The fundamental idea of "out of the loop" is to "be excluded from ongoing decision-making processes", hence the idea of "a **discussion** where important decisions are made". I don't think the idea of "update" is always entailed in the expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A widely used contemporary colloquial expression is "**отправлять в игнор**", as in "Меня отправили в игнор" - however, note that this is used almost solely by teens and younger people among themselves, and would be completely inappropriate otherwise. Note that "игнор" here is directly borrowed from the English "ignore".

Apart from that, I doubt that there is a stable counterpart for '**leaving** someone out of the loop', although there is one for '**getting (staying)** out of the loop': "**оказываться (быть) не в теме/не в курсе дела**".

*The guys were eagerly discussing something, but I found myself completely out of the loop*.

*Ребята что-то оживленно обсуждали, но я оказался совершенно не в теме*.

Comment: Along the same lines, keeping in the loop is держать в курсе, so you can say Я обиделся на них, потому что они не держали меня в курсе дела.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a universal compact expression for embedding into any context. However, that sense can be expressed indirectly where necessary, e. g. :

> Они обсуждали это так, будто меня (его, никого) рядом не было.
>
> Они и
>   *не подумали привлечь к обсуждению* меня или кого-то ещё из присутствовавших.
>
> Они обсуждали эту тему, *не считаясь с моим присутствием* (полностью
>   меня игнорируя).
>
> Они говорили об этом так, будто  меня это не касалось.

Answer (score 0):

Quite usable phrases, close to "leave someone out of the loop":

**Исключить из круга общения.**

**Выгнать из нашего круга.**

**Исключить из общего круга.**

**Исключить из узкого круга [избранных].**